# Websphere MQ Client installation

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am working on a project where MQ client (Support PAC 7) is installed on one 64-bit Linux machine and it sends messages to server.

On client machine we are using 64-bit linux JDK 1.6.25

java -version

```
 java version "1.6.0_25"
```

I have following environment variable set up

```
 MQSERVER='my_channel/tcp/SRVD10995(1414)'
 MQ_INSTALL_ROOT=/var/mqm/
 MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH=/var/mqm/
 MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH=/opt/mqm/java/
 MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH=/opt/mqm/java/lib64
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mqm/java/lib64
 CLASSPATH= /opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jar:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar:/opt/mqm/samp/jms/samples:/opt/mqm/samp/wmqjava/samples
```

but when I run following command

dspmqver -p 6

For native libraries I am seeing following message:

```
 Name:        IBM WebSphere MQ
 Version:     7.0.1.6
 CMVC Level:  k701-106-110721 mqjbnd=CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd' was not found. [3=mqjbnd]::no mqjbnd in java.library.path
 Build Type:  Production
```

I am also getting same error message when I execute JMS code to connect to server. I do not have libmqjbnd.so is not in the /opt/mqm/java/lib64 folder,  and not even in 32 bit folder.

I have couple of questions :

1) How do I fix this problem for client installation?
2) Does the library file (.so) need to be there in that directory ?

I will be thankful if anyone provides me answer to above questions, I have already invested many hours in this but no joy.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Technote on this specific question [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413508).  Let us know if the solution presented there does not resolve your problem.

Update: I noticed a mismatch between your CLASSPATH which is pointing to the 32-bit libs and the other variables pointing to the 64-bit libs.  WMQ provides scripts that set the variables for you [as described in the Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm10330_.htm):

```
On a UNIX system, you can use the script setjmsenv (if you are using a 32-bit 
JVM) or setjmsenv64 (if you are using a 64-bit JVM) to set the environment
variables. On AIX, these scripts are in the /usr/mqm/java/bin directory and,
on HP-UX, Linux, and Solaris, they are in the /opt/mqm/java/bin directory.
```

Many people source the scripts in their .profile.  Have you tried running these?  Remember that simply running the script...

```
/opt/mqm/java/bin/setjmsenv64
```

...does not result in the env vars being set in the current shell.  The script must be sourced using the dot syntax as follows:

```
. /opt/mqm/java/bin/setjmsenv64
```

What results do you get after sourcing the appropriate setjmsenv or setjmsenv64 script?

Comment: I cannot find the file there.

    ls -l /opt/mqm/java/lib/libmqjbnd.so
<BR>
    ls: /opt/mqm/java/lib/libmqjbnd.so: No such file or directory

Comment: Here is the list of components that are there.

rpm -qa | grep MQSeries
MQSeriesSamples-7.0.1-6
MQSeriesClient-7.0.1-6
MQSeriesJava-7.0.1-6
MQSeriesRuntime-7.0.1-6

I am not sure that, these components should have the file there or not??

Comment: Updated my response based on comments.  The file in question is used for bindings mode connections so I would not expect to find it in the client install. That something is looking for it would appear to be part of the native behavior where both client and bindings mode are tried. I suspect a configuration issue is what's causing it to not recognize it's a client-only install.

Comment: Yes I have tried using setjmsenv64 script, but it does not make any difference.
However when I run IVT program as specified in this
[link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc%2Fjm10330_.htm) 
It works fine.

But when I run that in tomcat native libraries come back and haunt me.

Comment: I think you are right about configuration issue , but I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: The IVT runs proves that it *can* work and all the parts are there.  Usually when the IVT runs and the other apps don't it comes down to differing environments or CLASSPATH issues. For example, sometimes when the WMQ jars are copied to the app server's CLASSPATH the IVT runs great because it points to the WMQ JRE and classes but the app fails because it points to the local copies. Sorry I don't have a smoking gun to point you to here but it looks like it comes down to reconciling the differences between the IVT environment versus the app environment.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you need the libraries depends how you want to send messages to the server. WebSphere MQ allows you to choose between bindings mode and client mode. Bindings mode uses the libraries with some IPC while client mode is purely Java and TCP based. 
If your programming language is Java then i would choose client mode.

Answer (score 0):

This message occurs also when you forget to set properties for host, port, ... 
This is in case of standalone MQ client.

```
MQEnvironment.hostname = "mqm.onZos.myCompany.com";
MQEnvironment.port = 1234;
MQEnvironment.channel = "SYSTEM.MYCH.NAME";
```